# I can't get confirmations for transaction

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Something weird happened with this tx 5a2b117611a4dc6ae53335b6e6d8ee9c146efaab54564f3ff1c3f3a4dddf5eed, it seems will never get confirmation. What the problem?

Comment: That Tx has a fee rate  of 61 s/vb. blockchair estimates 24 hours til confirmation.  A fee calculator says you need a rate of 325 to get a confirmation in the next 6 blocks.

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad actually no, because I don't see why it can't be confirmed. There was 2 confirmations and then they lost

Comment: @OleksandrIY That basically doesn't happen, it could be a bug in whatever software you're using to display confirmation status. Your fee rate of 61 sat/vB has been insufficient to get into a block for four days now, you just have to wait longer or increase the fee.

Comment: Your transaction just confirmed.